# what is the meaning of RMSE in caret::train

Tags: caret, rms

I'm confused by the exercise solutions of the book Applied Predictive Modeling. 
In

https://github.com/topepo/APM_Exercises/blob/master/Ch_06.pdf
at the beginning of page 4

```
Resampling results
  RMSE   Rsquared  RMSE SD  Rsquared SD
  1.382  0.8716    1.014    0.08729
The RMSE is slightly more than 1.4%
```

To my knowledge RMSE isn't a % (of what?)
It's

```
mse <- mean(residuals(fit)^2)
rmse <- sqrt(mse)
```

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

The Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) is calculated on the original scale. If the data to be predicted is in kilograms, your RMSE will be expressed in kilograms. If your data are in degrees Fahrenheit, your RMSE will be in degrees Fahrenheit.

In this specific case, your data are the fat content as a *percentage* of meat. Your data are percentages. So your RMSE will also be expressed in percent.

Comment: Then what is `Rsquared`?

Comment: @digitgopher: $R^2$ is related to the mean squared error. [Here is the Wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)